# Zend Studio 9 breaking on installing svn plugin

Tags: svn, zend-studio

I have Zend Studio 9 and there is an option to create a PHP project from SVN.  When I click on this, it tells me that it needs to install the SVN feature. I hit `OK`, and then during the ***calculating dependencies*** phase it errors out and says to look at the error log. I have looked everywhere and cannot find the error log. Not sure if this matters, but I also have TortoiseSVN installed. Also, on the welcome screen I checked for SVN support and svn1.7 connector.

The error that Eclipse throws is `Operation Details`.  Then when you click details it says `cannot complete request see error log`.

**Does anyone know how to fix this error?  Or, does anyone know where this error log resides?**

I'm looking to get this resolved. If it cannot be resolved, at least knowing where the error log is can provide me some insight onto resolving it myself.

Comment: What happens if you run it as an administrator?

Comment: Nope. Still errors out.

Comment: And it isn't currently installed right?  Can you try clicking window, open perspective, other, select SVN repository exploring.  Then click window, show view, SVN Repository Browser.  Are any of those options missing or error out?

Comment: There are no svn perspectives available. My understanding is that zend studio provides the option to use svn, but when you first use it, it has to install the feature.